# display list based on multiple radio button selections using Python Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am an absolute beginner in programming and to Python. I am trying to build a Random Meeting Host presenter to chair weekly meetings using Tkinter

So far this is what I have done:

1. You can click any radio button and you will see the list users per button
2. You can click the select host button and it will randomly select a user from a list that has all Users.

Issue:
I want to be able to select a button from the left (e.g Security Forum) and a button from the right (e.g Junior Engineers) and then display the result by clicking the "Display Selection button". It must keep only one entry and remove the duplicates. Basically, displaying the result (List of names) of multiple button selection

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import sys
import datetime

root = Tk()
root.title('Random User Entry')
root.geometry("700x600")
root.configure(borderwidth="1")
root.configure(relief="sunken")
root.configure(cursor="arrow")
root.configure(highlightbackground="white")
root.configure(highlightcolor="black")

# f = forum, e = engineers
f = IntVar()
e = IntVar()

security = ['Raven Kyle', 'Billy Joel','James Gonzalez','Maria Lopez', 'Justin Bright', 'Ali Baba']
networkcore = ['Tom Reeves', 'Joe Soap', 'John Smith', 'David Jones','Michael Johnson','Chris Lee']
unifiedcomms = ['Mary White', 'John Smith','Mike Brown','Mark Williams','Paul Rodriguez','Daniel Garcia']

# un = username | eng = engineer
junior_eng_un = ['Raven Kyle', 'Billy Joel','James Gonzalez','Maria Lopez', 'Justin Bright', 'Ali Baba','Tom Reeves',
             'Joe Soap', 'John Smith']
senior_eng_un = ['David Jones','Michael Johnson','Chris Lee','Mary White', 'John Smith','Mike Brown','Mark Williams',
             'Paul Rodriguez','Daniel Garcia']
all_eng_un = ['Raven Kyle', 'Billy Joel','James Gonzalez','Maria Lopez', 'Justin Bright', 'Ali Baba','Tom Reeves',
              'Joe Soap', 'John Smith', 'David Jones','Michael Johnson','Chris Lee','Mary White', 'John Smith',
              'Mike Brown','Mark Williams','Paul Rodriguez','Daniel Garcia']


def tick():
    datenow = datetime.datetime.now()
    time_string = datenow.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S:%p")
    clock.config(text=time_string)
    clock.after(200,tick)


clock = Label(root, font=("times", 12, "bold"), fg= "white", bg="black")
clock.grid(row=6, columnspan=1, pady=3)
tick()


def all_eng_host():
    # all engineering host - random selection of list all_eng_un, enter result in blue textbox
    un_in_numbers = len(all_eng_un) - 1
    rand_un = random.randint(0, un_in_numbers)
    selection_display = Text(master=root, height=17, width=20, bg="Lightblue", font="Helvetica 12 bold")
    selection_display.grid(row=5, column=0, padx=10)
    selection_display.insert(END, all_eng_un[rand_un])


def all_eng_display():
    # Selecting ALL Engineers and display in green box
    all_eng_display = Text( master=root, height=20, width=20, bg="Lightgreen", font ="Helvetica 10 bold" )
    all_eng_display.grid(row=5,column=1,padx=10)
    for i in all_eng_un:
        all_eng_display.insert(END, (i + "\n"))


def junior_eng_display():
    # Selecting only SA Engineers and display in green box
    junior_eng_display = Text( master=root, height=20, width=20, bg="Lightgreen", font ="Helvetica 10 bold" )
    junior_eng_display.grid(row=5,column=1,padx=10)
    for i in junior_eng_un:
        junior_eng_display.insert(END, (i + "\n"))


def senior_eng_display():
    # Selecting only UK Engineers and display in green box
    senior_eng_display = Text( master=root, height=20, width=20, bg="Lightgreen", font ="Helvetica 10 bold" )
    senior_eng_display.grid(row=5,column=1,padx=10)
    for i in senior_eng_un:
        senior_eng_display.insert(END, (i + "\n"))


def rs_forum_display():
    # Selecting only users part of networkcore forum and display in green box
    rs_forum_display = Text( master=root, height=20, width=20, bg="Lightgreen", font ="Helvetica 10 bold" )
    rs_forum_display.grid(row=5,column=1,padx=10)
    for i in networkcore:
        rs_forum_display.insert(END, (i + "\n"))


def sec_forum_display():
    # Selecting only users part of security forum and display in green box
    sec_forum_display = Text( master=root, height=20, width=20, bg="Lightgreen", font ="Helvetica 10 bold" )
    sec_forum_display.grid(row=5,column=1,padx=10)
    for i in security:
        sec_forum_display.insert(END, (i + "\n"))


def uc_forum_display():
    # Selecting only users part of unifiedcomms forum and display in green box
    uc_forum_display = Text( master=root, height=20, width=20, bg="Lightgreen", font ="Helvetica 10 bold" )
    uc_forum_display.grid(row=5,column=1,padx=10)
    for i in unifiedcomms:
        uc_forum_display.insert(END, (i + "\n"))


def show_selection():
    for pa in security:
        security_display = Text(master=root, height=20, width=20, bg="Lightgreen", font="Helvetica 10 bold")
        security_display.grid(row=5, column=1, padx=10)
        security_display.insert(END, pa)
    for rs in networkcore:
        networkcore_display = Text(master=root, height=20, width=20, bg="Lightgreen", font="Helvetica 10 bold")
        networkcore_display.grid(row=5, column=1, padx=10)
        networkcore_display.insert(END, (rs + "\n"))
        for uc in unifiedcomms:
            unifiedcomms_display = Text(master=root, height=20, width=20, bg="Lightgreen", font="Helvetica 10 bold")
            unifiedcomms_display.grid(row=5, column=1, padx=10)
            unifiedcomms_display.insert(END, (uc + "\n"))


def none_selected():
    # Display message if no options selected
    greeting1 = " "
    security_display = Text(master=root, height=20, width=20, bg="Lightgreen", font="Helvetica 10 bold")
    security_display.grid(row=5, column=1, padx=10)
    security_display.insert(END, greeting1)



topLabel = Label(root, text="GNC Random Meeting Host Selector", font=("Helvetica", 20))
topLabel.grid(row=0, columnspan=2, pady=5, padx=20)

myradiobutton1 = Radiobutton(root, text="Routing and Switching Forum", font=("Helvetica", 12),
                             variable=f, value=networkcore, command=rs_forum_display)
myradiobutton1.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
myradiobutton2 = Radiobutton(root, text="Security Forum", font=("Helvetica", 12),
                             variable=f, value=security, command=sec_forum_display)
myradiobutton2.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)
myradiobutton3 = Radiobutton(root, text="Unified Comms Forum", font=("Helvetica", 12),
                             variable=f, value=unifiedcomms, command=uc_forum_display)
myradiobutton3.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)

Radiobutton(root, text="Junior Engineers", font=("Helvetica", 12), variable=e, value=junior_eng_un, command=junior_eng_display).grid(row=1, column=1)
Radiobutton(root, text="Senior Engineers", font=("Helvetica", 12), variable=e, value=senior_eng_un, command=senior_eng_display).grid(row=2, column=1)
Radiobutton(root, text="All Engineers", font=("Helvetica", 12), variable=e, value=all_eng_un, command=all_eng_display).grid(row=3, column=1)

selection_button1 = Button(root, text="Click Here to Display Selection", command=none_selected)
selection_button1.grid(row=4, column=1, pady=10, padx=100)

hostButton = Button(root, text="Click to select next Meeting Host!", font=("Helvetica", 10), command=all_eng_host)
hostButton.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=10)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: Random List Button Selections]
[image: Case Study]

Comment: Do you mean that you don't want the green text box be updated when those radio buttons are clicked?

Comment: thanks for your response @acw1668. Yes. When I select an option from the left and option from the right it must update the green box by clicking on the "Display selection button". I'm not sure if checkboxes would be a better option but I hope you get the idea.

Comment: So what do you expect when you change either the forum selection or the engineer group selection, but do not click the `Display Selection` button and click the `Meeting Host` button?  In this case, the engineer list in the green box does not have the updated list for choosing the meeting host.

Comment: So I suggest to update the green box whenever the forum or the engineer group is changed (also clear the already chosen meeting host) and so the `Display Selection` button can be removed.

Comment: So in a forum, there can be Junior or Senior Engineers. So let's say I want to list the result of Senior Security Engineers in the display box, I will click Radiobutton Security Button and Radiobutton Senior Engineers and the result will get displayed. Please see Picture of my case study and it will explain what Im trying to achieve better. :)

Comment: I understand.  So I propose to update the green box whenever the forum or engineer group is changed and the `Display Selection` button is not required.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I will try that out. But what if I want Forum and Engineer group? How to combine 2 lists in a function,  and display the results without duplicates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to update the engineer selection list whenever the forum or the engineer group is changed and the `Display Selection` button is then not required.

Also better create the engineer selection box and update its content whenever required instead of creating new one when the forum or the engineer group is changed. Same for the host engineer chosen box as well.

Below is a modified and simplified example:

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import sys
import datetime

root = Tk()
root.title('Random User Entry')
root.geometry("700x600")
root.configure(borderwidth="1")
root.configure(relief="sunken")
root.configure(cursor="arrow")
root.configure(highlightbackground="white")
root.configure(highlightcolor="black")

# f = forum, e = engineers
f = IntVar()
e = IntVar()

networkcore = ['Tom Reeves', 'Joe Soap', 'John Smith', 'David Jones','Michael Johnson','Chris Lee']
security = ['Raven Kyle', 'Billy Joel','James Gonzalez','Maria Lopez', 'Justin Bright', 'Ali Baba']
unifiedcomms = ['Mary White', 'John Smith','Mike Brown','Mark Williams','Paul Rodriguez','Daniel Garcia']

# un = username | eng = engineer
junior_eng_un = ['Raven Kyle', 'Billy Joel','James Gonzalez','Maria Lopez', 'Justin Bright', 'Ali Baba','Tom Reeves',
                 'Joe Soap', 'John Smith']
senior_eng_un = ['David Jones','Michael Johnson','Chris Lee','Mary White', 'John Smith','Mike Brown','Mark Williams',
                 'Paul Rodriguez','Daniel Garcia']

def tick():
    datenow = datetime.datetime.now()
    time_string = datenow.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S:%p")
    clock.config(text=time_string)
    clock.after(200,tick)

clock = Label(root, font=("times", 12, "bold"), fg= "white", bg="black")
clock.grid(row=6, columnspan=1, pady=3)
tick()


def update_engineer_list():
    forum = f.get()
    engineer_group = e.get()
    if forum and engineer_group:
        # both forum and engineer group are selected
        forum_engineers = networkcore if forum == 1 else security if forum == 2 else unifiedcomms
        # get available engineers for the selected forum
        if engineer_group == 1: # junior
            engineers = [engineer for engineer in junior_eng_un if engineer in forum_engineers]
        elif engineer_group == 2: # senior
            engineers = [engineer for engineer in senior_eng_un if engineer in forum_engineers]
        elif engineer_group == 3: # all
            engineers = forum_engineers
        # update engineer list
        engineer_list.config(state=NORMAL)
        engineer_list.delete(1.0, END)
        engineer_list.insert(END, "\n".join(sorted(engineers)))
        engineer_list.config(state=DISABLED)
        # clear host engineer
        host_engineer["text"] = ""


def choose_host():
    # extract the engineer list from the engineer selection box
    engineers = engineer_list.get(1.0, "end-1c").split("\n")
    # then select one of them randomly
    host_engineer["text"] = random.choice(engineers)


topLabel = Label(root, text="GNC Random Meeting Host Selector", font="Helvetica 20")
topLabel.grid(row=0, columnspan=2, pady=5, padx=20)

fb1 = Radiobutton(root, text="Routing and Switching Forum", font="Helvetica 12", variable=f, value=1, command=update_engineer_list)
fb1.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, sticky=W)
fb2 = Radiobutton(root, text="Security Forum", font="Helvetica 12", variable=f, value=2, command=update_engineer_list)
fb2.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=10, sticky=W)
fb3 = Radiobutton(root, text="Unified Comms Forum", font="Helvetica 12", variable=f, value=3, command=update_engineer_list)
fb3.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=10, sticky=W)

eb1 = Radiobutton(root, text="Junior Engineers", font="Helvetica 12", variable=e, value=1, command=update_engineer_list)
eb1.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, sticky=W)
eb2 = Radiobutton(root, text="Senior Engineers", font="Helvetica 12", variable=e, value=2, command=update_engineer_list)
eb2.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=10, sticky=W)
eb3 = Radiobutton(root, text="All Engineers", font="Helvetica 12", variable=e, value=3, command=update_engineer_list)
eb3.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=10, sticky=W)

hostButton = Button(root, text="Click to select next Meeting Host!", font="Helvetica 10", command=choose_host)
hostButton.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=10, sticky=W)

# engineer list for selection
engineer_list = Text(root, width=30, height=20, bg="lightgreen", font="Helvetica 10 bold", state=DISABLED)
engineer_list.grid(row=5, column=1, padx=10, sticky=W)

# host engineer chosen
host_engineer = Label(root, width=20, height=2, bg="lightblue", font="Helvetica 14 bold", bd=2, relief=SUNKEN)
host_engineer.grid(row=5, column=0, padx=10, sticky=NW)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hi @acw1668, apologies for the late response. I didn't code for 2 days..... Lol. Thank you so much. I tried the code and it looks so much simpler and easier. I really appreciate your help and apologies for the many messages trying to resolve my situation.